# Screen capture when larger than display without scrolling

Tags: java, android, plugins, screen, capture

In any programming language, but preferably JAVA, I am trying to do screen captures from various browsers. I would like to capture the "whole" page, even the parts that one has to scroll to see.

A common method of achieving this is to capture the displayed, visible portion of the screen, then scroll to the next portion and capture it, and so on. One would then take these "tiles" and stitch them together in photoshop.

How can I capture the "whole" rendered page without scrolling? Is this possible. Is the page fully rendered but sitting in a video buffer somewhere? For example, let's say a page ends up rendering at 4000 x 4000 pixels. I want to capture the whole mess without scrolling.

I will want to do this for android, btw.

Comment: I really doubt that Android's browser fully renders a 4000x4000 pixel page completely, as this would be a major waste of the limited memory available on most devices.

Comment: Thx Ken, I was just using that as an example. Just any size that you'd have to scroll to see it all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Snagit has the ability to easily capture images from objects that are larger than the screen. Give it a try, it's recommended as one of the five best screen capture tools by lifehacker.

Features and free trial version download:
http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html